# How to prevent div elements from jumping which stays next to div which is animated by jQuery .slideToggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to build basic animation of two divs with jQuery .slideToggle() function.

The main concept is to toggle the visibility of two additional divs with map and contact form.

```
Here is the link to the demo on Codepen https://codepen.io/napvlm/pen/zXjzpv
```

The problem I have is that div with contact info (which is visible by default) jumping when additional div appears. How I can make it smoother and prevent it from jumping?

I tried to add CSS transitions, but any luck.

I am trying to achieve a smooth slide from the center to left back and force for div with contact info instead of jumping every time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://codepen.io/napvlm/pen/zXjzpv

Comment: Did you try position: absolute; on your .target-map, .target-form?

Comment: @RecepKaradas Oh really, thanks, now I will try to add additional JS to animate contact info to the left. Thank you, you helped me! :D

Comment: Glad I could help :)